# Is the following relation considered symmetric?

Tags: logic, relations, boolean-algebra, symmetric-functions

i'm having a little misunderstanding about how to determinate if a relation is symmetric ( in the case of a function)

So i have : $\{ \langle x,y\rangle \in\Bbb N^2 \mid x = y + 10\}$ , so the definition of the relation symmetric is saying $x R y \to y R x$ which in our case the inverse relation would be  $\{ \langle x,y\rangle \in\Bbb N^2 \mid x = y + 10\}$  OR $\{ \langle x,y\rangle \in\Bbb N^2 \mid y - 10 = x \}$

I'm wondering how do i check this mathematically ? do i just choose a random pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ and place it in the inverse relation ex: for $\langle 0,10\rangle$ we would have $xRy : 0 = 10+ 10$ and for $yRx : 10=10 + 0 $ so the two are not equal so its not symmetric ?

Thank you

Comment: What is meaning of E N^2 in the definitions?

Comment: @coffeemath It's supposed to be $ \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \ | \ x = y + 10 \} $.

Comment: sorry , yea thanks for the correction , <x,y> element of N^2

Comment: Tip for the future: Outside of MathJax delimiters, the less-than symbol will be mistaken for the start of an HTML tag, causing text following it to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate that a relation is *not* symmetric, it does suffice to find one counter example.

So indeed demonstrating that we have $10\mathcal R0$ and $\lnot 0\mathcal R10$ does the job.

More generally, it is clear that where ever $x=y+10$, there $y=x-10$, and so $y\neq x+10$.

Comment: Awesome thanks for enlightning me haha :) !

Comment: wait does <0,10> really works since its not on the line x = y + 10 ??

Comment: That's the point! @DanyPépin $\lnot 0\mathcal R10$ means $\lnot(0=10+10)$ . That is $0\neq 10+10$.  Thus $10$ relates to $0$ but $0$ does not relate to $10$, so we *do not have* symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out if it's symmetric, you check if $ \langle x, y \rangle $ and $ \langle y, x \rangle $ are in it for all $ x $ and $ y $.

So, let's do it with arbitrary $ x $s and $ y $s:

$$ \begin{align}
     x \mathrm{R} y &\wedge y \mathrm{R} x
\\   x = y + 10 &\wedge y = x + 10
\\   x = y + 10 &\wedge x = y - 10
\\   x &= x
\\   y + 10 &= y - 10
\\   10 &= -10
\\   &\textrm{False}
   \end{align}
$$

By universal introduction, we see that there are no values at all of $ x $ and $ y $ for which the relation is symmetric.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the answer :)